# Location of the script file in ScriptCS

Tags: scriptcs

When running a [ScriptCS](http://scriptcs.net/) .CSX script, is there a way to get the location of the current script file?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you can access that using `Env.ScriptPath` from inside your CSX script.

The test below shows that in action, and can be found [here](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/blob/c73d4650469f889b3ad6ba94ee8a470831efa428/test/ScriptCs.Tests.Acceptance/ScriptExecution.cs#L104).

```
[Scenario]
public static void ScriptPathIsSet(ScenarioDirectory directory, string output)
{
    var scenario = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetFullName();

    "Given a script which accesses Env.ScriptPath"
        .f(() => directory = ScenarioDirectory.Create(scenario)
            .WriteLine("foo.csx", "Console.WriteLine(Env.ScriptPath)"));

    "When I execute the script"
        .f(() => output = ScriptCsExe.Run("foo.csx", directory));

    "Then the ScriptPath is displayed"
        .f(() => output.ShouldContain("foo.csx"));
}
```